# IE9 messed up my application

Tags: c#, browser, internet-explorer-9

I have web scraping appliaction written in C# that uses a `WebBrowser`.

One of it's features is that it let the user write a javascript function that will be injected and invoked in web pages. This is a user made function that receives as a parameter a C# object that, among other things, contains a property called `UserData`, which the user can use to store whatever he wants and it will stay there even after the browser navigates to another page. It also contains a `Browser` object that I'll just use here as an example.

If I injected and called the following function when I had IE8 installed:

```
function ToBeInjected(Global)
{
    function Data()
    {
        this.csObject = Global.Browser;
        this.jsObject = "hi";
    }

    Global.UserData = new Data();
}
```

then navigated to another page and injected and called this function:

```
function ToBeInjected(Global)
{
    alert(Global.UserData.jsObject);    // works ok on IE8 and IE9 (shows "hi")
    alert(Global.UserData.csObject);    // works on IE8 (show the object's type) but not IE9 ("Permission Denied" error)
}
```

the second `alert` would work properly and show me the type of my `Browser` object (the `Global` object being passed here and to the previous function is the same object).

I know it might seem weird the the object existed after the browser navigated, but it did, and it always did and never had a problem with this, and my application used this as a feature.

But now I just installed IE9 and, objects still stay, but on this particular case on which the `UserData` is a javascript object (the `Data` object) that contains a pointer (or however you would call it) to an external C# object (the `Browser` object), I get a "Permission Denied" javascript error. (If I don't navigate and run both scripts in the same page it works fine on both IE versions.)

I know my example is useless, but it's just a sample. There are other cases on which it's useful to have a javascript object containing objects that points to external C# objects.

So, even though this is a super particular problem, do you have ANY suggestion on what could I do to solve it or why am I having this problem with IE9?

Comment: Javascript being able to address something on the system "outside" the browser is a scary concept. Any holes in the browser's security system, even if well-guarded, will always get exploited.

Comment: Any holes in the browser's security system will always get exploited no matter what. I though about that and I don't think it will be a problem for my case.

Comment: This isn't a security problem because the browser can only access what you put there.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want data to persist between pages.  Have you thought about either of the following:

1. Store the user data as cookies.  Read them back on on subsequent page loads
2. Use [window.external](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535246%28VS.85%29.aspx) to host an object in your C# code that persists between pages.

Comment: OK I just tested using window.external instead but it gives me the exact same problem. Cookies are text so are also useless for my particular case :(

Comment: Cookies only work within a given domain, can only contain text, and have fairly strict limits on total size.

Comment: @jsoldi: How did you use `window.external` to get that error?

Comment: The same as my code above but instead of passing `Global` as a parameter I set `ObjectForScripting` to `Global` and access it from my javascript code from `window.external`. So instead of `Global.UserData` I used `window.external.UserData`. But remember, I only get an error on the particular case I mention in my question.

Comment: The intent of my comment is that you implement an object in C# that attaches to window.external. That is, you implement "UserData" as a C# class with methods like "GetProperty" and "SetProperty".  Also, for cookies, you can still use text values provided you come up with a way to serialize your binary data to strings.  There are countless ways to do this.